# Rendering positioned divs alongside floating divs

Tags: css

css:::::

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}
button {
    position: absolute; 
}
```

html-body:::

```
<div>
        <div class="box" id="leftBox">
            <!--contains a header and jquery tree -->
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="rightBox">
          <!--contains a header and jquery tree-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button style="display:block;"> Run Test </button>
    </div>
```

gets rendered as,,,
[image]

why does the positioned button sits on top of floating objects? and isn't div element for button supposed to move it to next line?
How to move to the button to the next line and not to the right?

Comment: change position:relative; to button

Comment: button goes to right side, but i like to have button in the new line after the boxes...

Comment: @SathishS what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @BenjaminBlonde, the button must always be placed below the two rectangular boxes... putting the button inside div elements (or) display:block properties are not helping...

Comment: If you position any element absolutely it takes it out of the flow of the document, hence it appears to sit on top of other content. If you want it positioned absolutely inside another container, you can easily acheive this, by setting position relative on the parent. But if you have other content inside this element, that you wish to see you will have to use padding or margins or relative positioning to allow all elements to be viewed.

Comment: Well then I don't think you want absolute positioning at all. you should make a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made this for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/qft2bLdx/

It is a bit hacky.

I removed position:absolute from the button and added

```
 clear:both;
```

The better option would be to add the clearfix class to the wrapper containing the two box class elements.

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

So the best result would be:

***HTML***

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="box" id="leftBox">
        <!--contains a header and jquery tree -->
        Start Tests
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="rightBox">
      <!--contains a header and jquery tree-->
        Start Tests
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button> Run Test </button>
</div>
```

***Add CSS***

```
.clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="buttonDiv">
    <button style="display:block;"> Run Test </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
buttonDiv {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
}
button {
    position:relative; /* or just delete the rule */
}
```